# FirebaseDatabase Query - Filter where date is higher than now

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a number of Firebase Event items which have a datetime stores as Epoch.

What i would like to do i get the current time and then filter on results that havent happened yet. Currently i just order by datetime

So how do i add a condition to this to make "datetime" higher than "time"

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Events").orderByChild("datetime");
```

JSON

```
  "date" : "Sat 7th March",
  "datetime" : 1583618400,
```

Comment: That depends on how you store `datetime` in the database. Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON at `Events` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have added snippet. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't show us enough to be certain. I'll write my best guess answer below, but please make sure we see the `Events` node and some of its child nodes (including at least the relevant properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries follow a two-step process:

1. You order the child nodes under a location on a given property (`orderByChild`), value (`orderByValue`), or their key (`orderByKey`).
2. You tell the database what slice of the child nodes to return, using `startAt()`, `endAt()`, `equalTo()`, `limitToFirst()`, and `limitToLast()`.

In your case you'll want `startAt()` with something like:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child("Events")
        .orderByChild("datetime");
        .startAt(time + 1)
```

The `time + 1` here ensures that the results return are *after* the current time.

Comment: Perfectly explained and i understand it now. Thanks very much.